# Misdrank/leaked out of the mouth/spill on the floor(word choice)

Tags: word-choice

This is a word choice question-describing a minor mishap when a person is drinking any liquid.

> While I was sipping some of my coffee out of a cup, I **misdrank** it, and then it **leaked** **out** of my mouth causing some coffee to **spill** on the floor.

I don't think you can find this in a grammar book or any english book because what they teach are all basics and academic. Anyway, is this how *natives* *describe* a situation when some coffee out of a cup accidentally leaked and goes to the floor.

Comment: I don't think "misdrank" is a word.

Comment: I've never heard 'misdrank' before.  I'm not sure what kind of mishap is being described here.  I use 'inadvertently quaffed' to describe when the drink misses my mouth, but I don't think anyone outside of Discworld fandom is likely to understand it.

Comment: I just made 'misdrank' up... it's from a prefix mis-(like misstep), when I google it, there is a result but not to the same context I am trying to say. Anyway, could you correct it? *inadvertently quaffed sounds too slangy...

Comment: Note that "to quaff" does not mean that - it means to drink deeply, such as "I quaffed several beers in a few minutes."

Comment: Unfortunately, misdrank doesn't work. Quaff is not slangy at all. I drank it messily or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word [**slobber**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slobbered) means

> to allow saliva or food to run out of the mouth.

The sentence can be

> While I was sipping my coffee I slobbered, causing some to spill on the floor.

I simplified the detail about the cup which doesn't need to be mentioned.

Comment: Thx a lot, this is a handy sentence for much better communication.